# Consulta SQLITE Android Studio

Tags: sqlite

tengo una base de dato en sqlite en android studio, y al registrar un codigo "1", me guarda el codigo y la descripcion, pero al ingresar otro codigo "1" me dice que guarda los datos (pero no reescribe el codigo "1" solo dice que guardo) entonces necesito saber como puede mandar un TOAST que diga que ese codigo ya esta utilizado, aqui les dejo la clase de registrar.

```
public void Registrar(View view){
    AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "administracion", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase BaseDeDatos = admin.getWritableDatabase();

    String codigo = et_codigo.getText().toString();
    String descripcion = et_descripcion.getText().toString();
    String cantidad = et_cantidad.getText().toString();

    if(!codigo.isEmpty() && !descripcion.isEmpty() && !cantidad.isEmpty()){
        ContentValues registro = new ContentValues();

        registro.put("codigo", codigo);
        registro.put("descripcion", descripcion);
        registro.put("cantidad", cantidad);

        BaseDeDatos.insert("articulos", null, registro);

        BaseDeDatos.close();
        et_codigo.setText("");
        et_descripcion.setText("");
        et_cantidad.setText("");

        Toast.makeText(this,"Registro exitoso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Debes llenar todos los campos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

espero su ayuda! muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para comenzar no es una clase sino un método(de alguna clase),si he logrado entender lo que quieres es que necesitas saber si el numero: 1, ya existe en "articulos" tabla de la base de datos, entonces simplemente tienes que hacer un recorrido de la tabla para verificar y de tal modo poder mostrar en un `Toast` si ese dato ya existe o no.
Llamamos a la funcion: `verificarCodigo` que nos devolvera un booleano `true` si existe y `false` si no existe. seria algo asi:

```
        public void Registrar(View view){
    AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "administracion", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase BaseDeDatos = admin.getWritableDatabase();

    String codigo = et_codigo.getText().toString();
    String descripcion = et_descripcion.getText().toString();
    String cantidad = et_cantidad.getText().toString();

    if(!codigo.isEmpty() && !descripcion.isEmpty() && !cantidad.isEmpty()){


        if(verificarCodigo(codigo)){

            Toast.makeText(this,"el codigo: "+codigo +" Ya existe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }else{

            ContentValues registro = new ContentValues();

            registro.put("codigo", codigo);
            registro.put("descripcion", descripcion);
            registro.put("cantidad", cantidad);

            BaseDeDatos.insert("articulos", null, registro);

            BaseDeDatos.close();
            et_codigo.setText("");
            et_descripcion.setText("");
            et_cantidad.setText("");

            Toast.makeText(this,"Registro exitoso", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }




    } else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Debes llenar todos los campos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    }



    public boolean verificarCodigo(String codigo){

    AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "administracion", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase BaseDeDatoslectura = admin.getReadableDatabase();// leemos datos con: getReadableDatabase() 


    Cursor c;
    boolean b=false;
    c= BaseDeDatoslectura.rawQuery("SELECT codigo FROM articulos",null);
    //hacemos el recorrido  y preguntamos si existe un "1" en el campo codigo
    if (c.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            String buscar_codigo= c.getString(0);
            if(codigo.equal(buscar_codigo)){
                    b=true;
            }

        }while (c.moveToNext() && b==false);
    }

    return b;
}
```

Espero que sea lo que estés buscando.

Comment: muchisimas gracias, era justo lo que necesitaba!

Comment: para servir , Saludos